# How to Click on a Link after You click a Submit button

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

After I click a submit button, a new page opens over the existing window. Inside this new window, there is a link. How would you use WebDriver to click on this link? When I right-click on the link text and Inspect Element with Firebug, i get the following:

```
<a id="ctl100_ContentPlaceHolder1" class="prev-next previousYear" href="Enrollment2013.aspx?4fd70df97f0748ea82e787e5cf5b8552"><<previous year</a>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What about it confuses you? It's an element like everything else. You are currently finding specific elements using locators right now, yeah? So what's different with this?

Answer (score 0):

**Java:**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl100_ContentPlaceHolder1")).click();
```

**Python:**

```
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl100_ContentPlaceHolder1").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case you described, you have to switch to new window then operate there. Look at the code below:

```
String winHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); //Gets your current window handle.
for(String windowsHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(windowsHandle); //Switch to new window.
}
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl100_ContentPlaceHolder1")).click(); //Click on the link in new window
driver.close(); //Close the new window after your operations are performed.
driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); //Switch back to original window.
```

I believe this should help you :)